# True or False: if $X$ and $Y$ are indicator variables for $A$ and $B$, then $X+Y$ is an indicator variable for $A \cup B$

Tags: probability

> Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are indicator variables for events $A$, $B$ respectively, then $X+Y$ is always an indicator variable for $A \cup B$.

Also I need some help with the definition of an indicator variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The indicator random variable $X$ for the event $A$ is the random variable that takes on the value $1$ if the event $A$ occurs, and that takes on value $0$ if the event $A$ does not occur. So an indicator random variable can only take on values $1$ or $0$, basically $1$ for yes and $0$ for no.

Suppose now that $A$ and $B$ are events that can occur simultaneously. For example, $A$ could be the event of getting a sum of $7$ when you toss two dice like getting a sum of $7$ when you toss two dice. The event $B$ could be the event of getting at least one $5$.

Let $X$ be the indicator random variable for $A$, and $Y$ the indicator random variable for $B$. If we toss our dice, and get a $5$ and a $2$, then both $A$ and $B$ have happened. Note that in this case $X+Y$ takes on the value $2$, so cannot be an indicator random variable for anything. In particular, it is not the indicator random variable for $A\cup B$.

Answer (score 3):

Given a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ and an event $A\in\mathcal{F}$, the indicator variable $\mathbf{1}_A$ on $\Omega$ is
$$\mathbf{1}_A(\omega)=\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if }\omega\in A,\\
0 & \text{if }\omega\notin A
\end{cases}$$
([see Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function)). Note that an indicator function can **only** take on the values $0$ and $1$. If we take any non-empty $A\in\mathcal{F}$, and let $A=B$ in your problem, then clearly
$$\mathbf{1}_A+\mathbf{1}_B=\mathbf{1}_A+\mathbf{1}_A=\begin{cases}
2 & \text{if }\omega\in A,\\
0 & \text{if }\omega\notin A
\end{cases}$$
which is not the indicator function for $A\cup B=A\cup A=A$ (or any other set!) since it will take the value $2$ somewhere.

However, a correct statement is
$$\mathbf{1}_{A\cup B}=\mathbf{1}_A+\mathbf{1}_B-\mathbf{1}_{A\cap B},$$
which is essentially just a restatement of the [inclusion–exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).